# Reasoning about the number of ways to do something (with repetition)

Tags: combinatorics

The question is "How many ways are there to give 5 different gifts to 3 children?".

1: I reason: Awesome, each child has 5 independent choices of gifts. So $5*5*5 = 5^3$.

2: The solution reasons: Not so fast, mr wise-guy. The answer is actually $3*3*3*3*3 = 3^5$. Supposedly the solution reasons "each of the 5 presents has 3 independent choices of which silly kid it goes to".

While I understand approach 2 when pondering about it, I fail to understand why approach 1 doesn't work? And why the two answers differ so dramatically? Is there away of thinking to avoid error on this sort of problem? Perhaps some way of thinking in terms of domain and ranges?

Comment: Suppose you do what answer1 suggests.  You pick *a* gift for the first child.  You pick *a* gift for the second child... and it could have been the same gift as was given to the first child.  You pick *a* gift for the third.  What does that final result look like?  You've given up to three of the five gifts leaving at least two gifts ungiven, and its possible that multiple children both received the same gift and will fight over it complaining its their turn to play with it.

Comment: The 3 children don't all have $5$ independent choices. After a child pick a gift, the next child then have fewer choices. The question and solution 2 also considers that  some child(ren) may get no gifts. :(

Comment: Think of balls in boxes.  Here, the children are the boxes.  The balls are all distributed... and a ball can go into only one box at a time.

Comment: For this and other "balls in bins" problems, see [twelvefold way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way).

Comment: Following your first approach, the first child has not 5 choices but a lot more choices:
choosing no gifts, 1 gift out of 5, 2 gifts out of five and so forth. There are 20 ways to pick 2 gifts out of five alone.

Comment: Change the numeric values. For example 1 gift instead of 5, and still 3 children.  So $1^3$ for answer n°1 compared to $3^1$ for answer n°2. $1^3$ is egal to $1$, it is obvious that we have more than 1 way to give 1 gift to 1 in 3 children.

Answer (score 3):

You're right that you should be thinking of (a function's) domain and ranges, but equally you could have solved the problem with simpler reasoning. The first one doesn't work because  the same gift cannot be given to multiple children.

Therefore we can accurately think of the set of gifts as the domain $A$ (recall that a function cannot be one-to-many).

Let's think of the set of children as the range $B$. Then the question is equivalent to "how many functions $f:A\to B$ are there?"

Indeed you've just discovered that the answer is $|B|^{|A|}$. This is why mathematicians often use the notation $f\in B^A$ (even for infinite sets).

Answer (score 1):

As noted in comments your first approach fails because the choices of the kids are not independent. If one kid has obtained a gift another kid cannot get it.

However if one pursues the approach to the end one obtains still the correct result. Assume the kids took $i$, $j$ and $k=5-i-j$ gifts, respectively. For given $i,j,k$ there are altogether
$$
\frac{5!}{i!j!k!}
$$
distinct ways to distribute the gifts. After summing all possibilities one obtains:
$$
\sum_{i,j,k\ge0}^{i+j+k=5}\frac{5!}{i!j!k!}=3^5.
$$

Comment: It might be helpful to note that the reason the final expression holds is similar to why $\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r}=2^n$